# WPF native AvalonDock

Tags: .net, wpf, avalondock

Just to get you fast in context:

I am researching to develop a desktop application using floating/dockable/pinnable panels in .NET. The result should be similar to the different panels recent versions of Visual Studio uses. Definitely this is what the AvalonDock package offers.

I found out that this feature was not native in early WPF versions, and I am afraid that, even for me this is a basic and very useful feature, it is still not.

There is a lot of old info that may be outdated and I could not find concrete info about AvalonDock native support, there is just info about the AvalonDock package which could be innovative and impressive some years ago, but from my point of view nowadays should be already standardized and moreover when Microsoft is using them in their own products.

So my question is...

- is it true that has not been standardized? and if so... why?

It is very useful to drag and drop the different panels and place them as you want. Less work for the developer, less work for the designer and final user can be happy placing the different menus as she/he wants. I thought that this goals where very important when writing a library or framework, I can't believe that if they realized those advantages for VS that they are not available for the rest of the developers as well.

Answer (score 2):

*Is it true that has not been standardized? and if so... why?*

If I understand correctly, the word "standardized" means no bugs and no errors.
I've used this `AvalonDock` in [Prism](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/) applications and I've never met any bug or error when I use AvalondDock.

Moreover, AvalonDock is [free open source software](https://avalondock.codeplex.com). And [it can be downloaded](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AvalonDock/) by Nuget.

**Update:**

*With standardized I mean that is included in WPF.*

No, Microsoft hasn't included AvalonDock in **.Net Framework**.

If you mean that you should always add AvalonDock library to all newly installed applications, then you should just add AvalonDock libraries into install package. Read this [Create Setup and Deployment of WPF Application Step by Step](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dpatra/create-setup-and-deployment-of-wpf-application-step-by-step/) and this [deploying wpf application with clickonce deployment techniques](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/37db1d/deploying-wpf-application-with-clickonce-deployment-techniques/).

Comment: Hi @StepUp, thanks for your reply. With standardized I mean that is included in WPF. So no extra package is needed. I consider this feature quite old, stable and good enough for the Microsoft guys to include it.

Comment: thanks for the confirmation and link tutorials. What I am missing is the why, I consider it quite important.

Comment: sorry but provided links have nothing to do with AvalonDock or similar.

Comment: @juagicre I've updated links. This links show the basic approaches to deploy WPF application.

Comment: but this is nothing I ask. I know WPF basics already. My question is about a good reason Microsoft hasn't included this feature yet in WPF. I do not need code nor tutorial. Anyway thanks!

Comment: @juagicre cause Microsoft has not developed AvalonDock. Microsoft includes just own developed software products or software of companies which is bought by Microsoft.

Comment: it is obvious that Microsoft is not going to use this code, but they have already something similar (as said in initial question) in VS. Why don't they make it available for us in WPF?